# setAttribute use for Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I have 3 nested divs..

```
<div onclick="highlight(this)">1  
   <div onclick="highlight(this)">2
     <div onclick="highlight(this)">3 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**To stop event-bubbling**, I want add a syntax to the divs - **stopPropagation()**.

I've tried (for first div only here)

```
document.querySelectorAll("div")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "event.stopPropagation()");
```

But it's not working. What is the solution/alternative to this..??

I want the divs to be like..

```
<div onclick="highlight(this) event.stopPropagation()">1
```

Comment: I have a highlight function which colors the divs.. in event-bubbling, all 3 will get colored one by one.. To stop this, I want to add stopPropagation using Javascript

Comment: Have you tried adding a semicolon in between the two statements in your last example: `<div onclick="highlight(this); event.stopPropagation()">1`

Comment: The problem has been solved.. actually, setAttribute was probably overwriting the highlight, that was also to be taken care of..

And I did forget the semi-colon.. Thanks for the help .. :)
Pls remove the downvote if you've done it..

Comment: `.setAttribute()` makes no sense the way you were using it - for one thing it takes _two_ arguments (the name of the attribute you want to set and the value you want to set it to), but more importantly it is not the way to try to control the `event` object. I didn't downvote.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for noticing the mistake.. I wrote the syntax wrong here, which I've edited now.

Answer (score 1):

As you need to stop propagation of *event*, it seems to make sense that the corresponding action is attached to event itself. Here's one possible way of using it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer" onclick="highlight(event, this)">
    <div id="middle" onclick="highlight(event, this)">
        <div id="inner" onclick="highlight(event, this)">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function highlight(event, target) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log( target.id + ' is clicked' );
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hEzuT/).

Comment: That won't work. `this` isn't the `event` object: the way the OP is calling the function `this` will be `window`.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right, thank you. In fact, your suggestion - adding `event.stopPropagation` into `onclick` attribute directly - will work too, of course. )